# simplifying exponential equation that has a natural logarithm

Tags: exponentiation

I have the following equation:

$$y=\exp(C_1-C_2\ln x)$$

where $C_1$ and $C_2$ are constants.

I believe that the following is correct:

$$y=\exp C_1\exp (-C_2\ln x)$$

$\exp C_1$ is just a constant. I know that the exponent of the natural logarithm of $x$ is just $x$.  But I'm not sure what to do with $C_2$.

Comment: This is

$$y=\frac{e^{C_1}}{x^{C_2}}.$$

Comment: Notice that (1) $\exp C_1$ is itself a positive constant (an arbitrary one if $C_1$ can take on any real value), and (2) $\exp(-C_2 \ln x) = (e^{\ln x})^{-C_2}=x^{-C_2}$, where the expression on the right-hand side is restricted to $\operatorname{dom} \ln = (0, \infty)$.

Comment: Note that $\exp(\ln x) = x$, $\exp(-x) = 1/\exp(x)$ and $\exp(ab) = \left(\exp(a)\right)^b$